# Should I switch to Java 7 on my desktop already? Are there incompabilities? Or should I wait?

Tags: java

Java 7 has beeen released last month: [Oracle Blog](http://blogs.oracle.com/javase/entry/java_7_has_released)

I'm a private desktop user and I'm considering upgrading my Java 6 SE to Java 7 SE. Can I switch to Java 7 already safely?
I'm using not many Java programs. My main Java programs I use are:

- Eclipse Helios
- Libre Office 3.3.3
- JDownloader

Is there somewhere in the Internet a incompability list for Java 7 ? I wonder how good the backwards compability for Java 7 is. I've found no information on the net.

Comment: From the java.com download page: **Recommended Version 6 Update 27**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory Java 7 is backwards compatible, but it had some known problems with the original release, see http://www.developerfusion.com/news/123346/java-7-breaks-apache-projects/ A fix already exists and should be already included in the official download. Basing on this, I'd wait.